# How to restrict in input of AutoNumeric negative values?

Tags: jquery, laravel-5, money-format

I installed autoNumeric and use in my laravel 5.7/ blade / jQuery v3.3.1 / Bootstrap v4.1.2 app, but I failed
to set resrictions on only positive decimals(that is money field, different currencies, not only $ or euro).

Reading this https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric these rules seems rather complicated. I tried as

```
new AutoNumeric('#money_field', {
    currencySymbolPlacement: 'p',
    currencySymbol: ‘ PND’,
    maximumValue: '9999999999.99',
    numericPos : 0.01
});
```

But failed, as negative value can be entered.
Which is the valid way ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation is very unclear but looking at the source you can see that `numericPos` is actually a set of predefined options (not an option in itself): https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/blob/403cf92366976a1c5df6689074242957e6f9c118/src/AutoNumericPredefinedOptions.js#L216

The one you need is `minimumValue`.

```js
new AutoNumeric('#money_field', {
    currencySymbolPlacement: 'p',
    currencySymbol: ' PND',
    maximumValue: '9999999999.99',
    minimumValue: 0
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/autonumeric/4.1.0/autoNumeric.min.js"></script>

<input id="money_field" />
```